# Grok doesn't match multiline log entries properly?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, multiline, logstash-grok, filebeat

I've been going at this for weeks now and I can't seem to wrap my head around what's wrong about this.

I'm trying to get all of these lines to fit into a multiline match with grok, but it only picks up the last one, and even discards the digit at the beginning of the line.

```
11:31:03.936    <           :     1>    5: Load times per type (ms):
12: aaaaaa.aaaaaaaaa.aaaaaaa.aaaaaaa
1: bbbb.bbbb.bbbbbbbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbbb
3: cccc.cccccccc.ccccccccccc.cccccc
64: ddd.dddddddddddd.ddddddd.ddddddd
```

Expected result:

```
message_processed = Load times per type (ms):
12: aaaaaa.aaaaaaaaa.aaaaaaa.aaaaaaa
1: bbbb.bbbb.bbbbbbbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbbb
3: cccc.cccccccc.ccccccccccc.cccccc
64: ddd.dddddddddddd.ddddddd.ddddddd
```

Actual result:

```
message_processed = ddd.dddddddddddd.ddddddd.ddddddd
```

I'm using the following grok pattern:

```
grok {
        match => [ "message" , "%{TIME:time}.*%{NUMBER:loglevel}:\s%{GREEDYDATA:message_processed}" ]
    }
```

It is being shipped to logstash with filebeat on a windows server with the following multi-line config in `filebeat.yml`:

```
multiline.pattern: ^[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}
multiline.negate: true
multiline.match: after
```

I've tried using (?m) flag but to no avail, and using multi-line codec with filebeat is a no-go according to the official documentation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
%{TIME:time}.*%{NUMBER:loglevel}:\s(?<message_processed>(.|\‌​r|\n)*)
```

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26475308/5730444) `GREEDYDATA` won't match newlines while `(?<message>(.|\r|\n)*)` will. So the above works for me.

See the results for your example with your multiline config on https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match:
[image: results]

Comment: I tried that a while back, and it didn't seem to make any difference. But for the sake of being thorough i changed it again so that now it reads:
`"%{TIME:time}.*%{NUMBER:loglevel}:\s(?<message_processed>(.|\‌​r|\n)*)"`
And now, it fails to load the logs at all. If i change it back to the grok expression, logs start loading again.