# logstash parse complex message from Telegram

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm processing through Telegram history (txt file) and I need to extract & process quite complex (nested) multiline pattern.
Here's the whole pattern

```
Free_Trade_Calls__AltSignals:IOC/ BTC (bittrex)

BUY :  0.00164

SELL :

TARGET 1 : 0.00180
TARGET 2 : 0.00205
TARGET 3 : 0.00240

STOP LOS : 0.000120
2018-04-19 15:46:57 Free_Trade_Calls__AltSignals:TARGET
```

basically I am looking for a pattern starting with

```
Free_Trade_Calls__AltSignals: ^%(
```

and ending with a timestamp.
Inside that pattern (telegram message)

```
 - exchange - in brackets in the 1st line 
 - extract value after BUY 
 - SELL values in a array of 3 SELL[3] : target 1-3
 - STOP loss value (it can be either STOP, STOP LOSS, STOP LOS)....
```

I've found this [Logstash grok multiline message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307965/logstash-grok-multiline-message) but I am very new to logstash firend advised it to me. I was trying to parse this text in NodeJS but it really is pain in the ass and mad about it.

Thanks Rob :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to grab values from each line, you don't need to use multi-line modifier. You can skip empty line with `%{SPACE}` character.

For your given log, this pattern can be used,

```
Free_Trade_Calls__AltSignals:.*\(%{WORD:exchange}\)\s*BUY\s*:\s*%{NUMBER:BUY}\s*SELL :\s*TARGET 1\s*:\s*%{NUMBER:TARGET_1}\s*TARGET 2\s*:\s*%{NUMBER:TARGET_2}\s*TARGET 3\s*:\s*%{NUMBER:TARGET_3}\s*.*:\s*%{NUMBER:StopLoss}
```

please note that `\s*` equals to `%{SPACE}`
It will output,

```
{
  "exchange": [
    [
      "bittrex"
    ]
  ],
  "BUY": [
    [
      "0.00164"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "0.00164",
      "0.00180",
      "0.00205",
      "0.00240",
      "0.000120"
    ]
  ],
  "TARGET_1": [
    [
      "0.00180"
    ]
  ],
  "TARGET_2": [
    [
      "0.00205"
    ]
  ],
  "TARGET_3": [
    [
      "0.00240"
    ]
  ],
  "StopLoss": [
    [
      "0.000120"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: so that's the pattern in input? and I don't need any filter right and also how to deal with the output you know I am new to this.

Comment: `input` is path to your log file and the provided pattern is actually a `grok` filter, please have a read at this, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html